# OS X Bash Script: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash

I tried learning how to write a bash script to have my own script to start and stop a Tomcat Server, and I can't seem to find what is causing the error in this script. I've double checked my `if` and `fi` statements to make sure they match, but still have no idea what is wrong.

EDIT:
Here is the exact error message

`line 87: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Returns the process id of the Tomcat server if currently running
function tomcat_pid {
        local pid=0
        local temp=$(ps x | grep "$CATALINA_HOME" | grep -v grep | cut -d ' ' -f 1)

        if [ -n "$temp" ]; then
                pid=$temp
        fi
        echo "$pid"
}#tomcat_pid

#Checks the status of the Tomcat Server
function tomcat_status {
        local retval="Tomcat Server is not currently running"

        local pid
        pid=$(tomcat_pid)

        if [ "$pid" -gt 0 ]; then
                retval="Tomcat Server is running at pid: $pid"
        fi

        echo "$retval"
}#tomcat_status

#Starts the Tomcat Server
function tomcat_start {
        local pid
        pid=$(tomcat_pid)

        if [ "$pid" -gt 0 ]; then
                echo "Tomcat Server already running at pid: $pid"
        else
                echo "Starting Tomcat Server"
                "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh"
        fi
}#tomcat_start

#Stops the Tomcat Server
function tomcat_stop {
        local pid
        pid=$(tomcat_pid)

        if [ "$pid" -gt 0 ]; then
                echo "Shutting down Tomcat Server"
                "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh"
        else
                echo "Tomcat Server is not currently running"
        fi
}#tomcat_stop

#Restarts the Tomcat Server
function tomcat_restart {
        local pid
        pid=$(tomcat_pid)
        if [ "$pid" -gt 0 ]; then
                echo "Restarting the Tomcat Server"
               "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh"
                sleep 5s
                "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/start.sh"
        else
                echo "Starting the Tomcat Server"
                "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh"
        fi
}#tomcat_restart

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        if [ "$1" = 'restart'  ]; then
                tomcat_restart
        #tomcat start - Starts the Tomcat Server
        elif [ "$1" = 'start' ]; then
                tomcat_start
        #tomcat shutdown - Shuts down the Tomcat Server
        elif [ "$1" = 'shutdown' ]; then
                tomcat_stop
        #tomcat status - Checks the status of the tomcat server
        elif [ "$1" = 'status' ]; then
                tomcat_status
        else
                echo "Please use correct options"
        fi
else
        echo "Please use correct options"
fi
```

Comment: You need a space between the `}` and `#` for the comments.

Comment: You've got the relevant answer (as a comment).  Observation: "Please use correct options" is vastly unhelpful when you use the command 6 months later and can't remember what the correct options are.  You should report a summary of the correct usage to jog the user's memory.  For example, `echo "Usage: $0 {restart|start|shutdown|status}" >&2; exit 1` reports the usage on standard error and ensures that the script reports an error status (`exit 0` indicates success).

Comment: Scripts to start and stop services are not really a good exercise for beginners, and pointless when you are not a beginner.

Comment: @tripleee why are they pointless for non beginners ?

Comment: @123 Maybe I got a bit carried away by rhetoric. To nuance that statement a bit: Service scripts are a solved problem; reinventing them from scratch is not something an experienced developer would do. This is little more than a (poor) reimplementation of `pidof`, though parts of the logic are probably useful, and even potentially necessary; though most modern services would already come with a simple start/stop script if they need one.

Answer (score 1):

See `man bash`, in other words `bash(1)`, Section SHELL GAMMAR

```
   { list; }
          list  is  simply executed in the current shell environment.  list must be terminated with a newline or semi‐
          colon.  This is known as a group command.  The return status is the exit status of list.  Note  that  unlike
          the  metacharacters ( and ), { and } are reserved words and must occur where a reserved word is permitted to
          be recognized.  Since they do not cause a word break, they must be separated  from  list  by  whitespace  or
          another shell metacharacter.
```

The last sentence points at your problem.

Comment: No, the last sentence explains why there is a space *before* the closing `}`.

Comment: basically yes, but a shell script is a big `list;` at its main level.